# pip cannot find installed packages in anaconda

Tags: python, pip

I wrote my own package with `setup.py`, in my setup.py file, I have:

```
install_requires=[
    "numpy",
    "scipy",
    "matplotlib",
    "python-pptx",
    "xlrd",
    "xlwt",
    "pillow",
],
```

these packages are already installed, and I want to install to my `anaconda root env`, so if I run `pip install -e .`, `pip` cannot find all the required packages are already installed, it tries to install all of them again:

```
Collecting numpy (from elc-pytools==0.1.0)
Using cached numpy-1.11.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

but if I run `python setup install`, it finds the installed packages:

```
Using c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Searching for numpy==1.11.0
Best match: numpy 1.11.0
Adding numpy 1.11.0 to easy-install.pth file
```

Why is that? And is there a way to tell `pip` that the required packages are already installed?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `pip` that came with Anaconda? Try `where pip` on the command line

Comment: i am sure of that, it is under: c:/anaconda3/script/pip.exe

Comment: Is Anaconda up to date? Try `conda update --all`

Comment: Is there a PYTHONPATH environment variable set?

Comment: just checked, nope, no PYTHONPATH